# how to send instance to ModelForms and fill form with that instance

Tags: python, django

I have this form:

```
class TourForm(ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = Tour
```

I wanna design a edit page,so i send tour_id to page and get tour with that tour_id,now I wanna fill this form with tour instance I've gotton.some thing like this in views.py:

```
tour=Tour.objects.get(pk=tour_id)
tform = TourForm(request.POST, request.FILES,instance=tour)
```

any help?

**update:**

these are models:

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
   HeadImage = models.ImageField(upload_to="gallery")

class Image(models.Model):
   Image = models.ImageField(upload_to="gallery")
   Gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery, related_name='images')



class Tour(models.Model):
   Name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
   Count=models.SmallIntegerField() 
   PriceUnit=models.ForeignKey(PriceUnit)
   Price=models.CharField(max_length=12)
   Description=models.TextField()
   ActionDate=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,editable=False)
   ActionUser=models.ForeignKey(User,editable=False)
   StatusType=models.ForeignKey(StatusType)
   Gallery = models.OneToOneField(Gallery,editable=False)
```

fields that are foreigkey like PriceUnit and StatusType,doesn't fill in form.

thanks in advance

Comment: sorry! I updated the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should not pass instance nad request.POSt at the same time. Try to do something like this:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    tform = TourForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
else
    tform = TourForm(instance=tour)
```

Comment: Any reasons not to pass them together?

Comment: @DrTyrsa generally because doing so triggers form validation. `Form({})` is an invalid form, and will display errors.